# Use a for loop to get sum in static add method and return it to main method

Tags: java, for-loop, static-methods

I'm having trouble getting the for loop right, in the static method so i can obtain a sum of the even numbers between two end points and return the sum to the main method. how would go by doing it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculate {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1, num2;

    System.out.print("Enter two integers: ");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    String input;
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    input = keyboard.next();



    if(input.equals("add"))
    {
        while(num1%2==0 && num1<num2)
        {
            int sum;
            sum = add(num1, num2);
            System.out.print("The sum of two integers is: " + sum);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    else if(input.equals("multiply"))
    {
        int product;
        product = multiply(num1, num2);
        System.out.print("The product of two integers is: " + product);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error, invalid input!");
    }




}   
public static int add(int number1, int number2)
{
    for(add = 0, add > 0, ++add)
    {   
    int result;
    result = number1 + number2;
    return result;
    }
}
public static int multiply(int number1, int number2)
{
    int result;
    result = number1 * number2;
    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: Any questions? Any errors? Should we just guess what your question is?

Comment: The error that came up was syntax error, add cannot be resolved to a variable
Also it says insert a block statement

Comment: Please next time read the [FAQ], and apply some common sense: if you have the error, and **where it occurred**, please share it with those who you want help from.

Comment: `for(add = 0, add > 0, ++add)` in function `add()` is your syntax error. It also does nothing to help with adding the even numbers between `number1` and `number2`

Comment: Also i was thinking of asking if the for(expression) should be initialized to the int num1 instead of the int add of the static method because i'm not clear on where the mistake is in the syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite the `add()` method, it doesn't make sense. This is how it should look, according to the description in the question:

> ...So I can obtain a sum of the even numbers between two end points and return the sum to the main method

```
public static int add(int number1, int number2) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And call it from `main()` like this:

```
if (input.equals("add")) {
    int sum = add(num1, num2);
    System.out.print("The sum of even numbers is: " + sum);
}
```

Notice that you should avoid calling `System.exit(0)`, in particular, don't ever call it inside a loop! it'll exit the program after just one iteration.

Comment: The while loop i had in the if statement was need to validate that the 1st integer is even and less than the 2nd integer. Now that i removed it, how can i validate it with the while loop?

Comment: @user2807804 That validation wasn't working, because you weren't modifying `num1` or `num2` and there was a `System.exit(0)` inside the loop. Try doing that validation _before_ calling `add`, and adjust it according to what you want to do (advance `num1` until it's even? exit the condition? I don't know)

Comment: the while loop will only exit if num1 is not even and when its odd

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use loops and so on.
Why don't you use the formula?

> SUM OF EVEN NUMBERS:
>
> Formula: N(N+1)  How to Find N = (First Even + Last Even)/2 - 1
>
> Example: 2+4+6+ ....... 100  N = (2+100)/2 - 1 = 50
>
> Sum of first 50 positive even integers = (50)(51) = 2550

http://www.beatthegmat.com/formula-for-consecutive-even-odd-integers-t17241.html

Comment: We are asked to use the for loop, no other method is accepted

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the `for` loop in your `add` method is that you set the value of add to zero, then check if add > 0.

Basically, a `for` loop expands out like this:

```
for (int a=0; a<15; a++)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

Becomes

```
  int a = 0;
  while (a < 15) {
    //Do Something
    a++;
  }
```

So rewriting your for loop, you get

```
int add=0;
while (add > 0) {
  int result;
  result = number1 + number2;
  return result;
  ++add;
}
```

Now, putting aside issues such as the `return result;` bit inside the `for` loop, or why you are even using a `for` loop here, you can at least see that you will never actually enter the loop the way it is written.